# httpd showing in error state with brew services list on MacOS Monterey

Tags: homebrew, launchd, apache, monterey, webserver

When I look at my services installed with Homebrew Apache is always in an error state. When I do a syntax check on my Apache config it is fine and Apache is serving up content fine.

It's only a minor inconvenience, but I figure there's something wrong there and i'd like to fix it if possible.

```
brew services list
Name          Status     User         File
etcd          started    crmpicco ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.etcd.plist
httpd         error  256 root         ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist
php@7.4       started    crmpicco ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.php@7.4.plist
postgresql@12 started    crmpicco ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql@12.plist
```

```
apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
*:443                  crmpicco.localhost (/usr/local/etc/httpd/extra/httpd-ssl.conf:121)
ServerRoot: "/usr/local/opt/httpd"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/usr/local/var/log/httpd/error_log"
Mutex default: dir="/usr/local/var/run/httpd/" mechanism=default 
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
PidFile: "/usr/local/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="_www" id=70 not_used
Group: name="_www" id=70 not_used
```

Comment: I fixed this somehow by checking `~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.httpd.plist` which had the wrong path to the httpd which I got from `brew info httpd` ... next gets fuzzy as I did a `brew reinstall` but not sure it was `httpd` or `php` or another application (I lost my zsh history) but `brew` started auto update lost of tools. After a full reboot my `httpd` came back alive.